# Can React be added to an existing .NET Core project?

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I am wondering how to add React into an existing ASP.NET Core MVC project in Visual Studio 2022 (no, I cannot use VS Code). I can see templates in VS2022 to create new React projects, but I have been unable to find any tutorials, videos, blogs or vlogs to show how to add React into an existing project, so I am wondering if it can be done.

I have added `react.js` and `react-dom.js` to the project and I am able to create pure javascript components using those (no JSX), but I would like to utilize more of what React has to offer.

=========================================

After the request to ask a more specific question, including the project in question . . .

I am currently on a small team working on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC application. It is currently using jQuery and jQuery-UI components within the CSHTML views for the UI. There are some `$.ajax` calls to an API for data, but most data is loaded with the model of the view.

My boss has asked me to look into utilizing React and the reusable components on the next module that we will be working on, without replacing the entire app into a "new React application".

Every single example, video, tutorial that I have watched uses VS Code or some other IDE (other than Visual Studio) to run commands on the CLI to "Create New React App", but nothing on how to "Add React to an Existing App".

Before I go back to him and tell him that I do not think we will be able to do what he is asking, I thought I would see if anyone here could point me to anything that could show that it could be done.

**Specific question**: can React be added to an existing ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app in Visual Studio Professional 2022 in a way that will allow linting, testing and JSX for reusable React components?

Comment: it is possible to add full react to a net 6 project for sure. since react is really just a folder with stuff and some node packages plus webpack.... so i dont see why not just add a new react app to the project and wire it up using the Spa serivices available in asp.net core

Comment: When Microsoft introduced JavaScript projects in VS2022, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/the-new-javascript-typescript-experience-in-vs-2022-preview-3/ the goal is to separate the two worlds and resolve all those issues with previous combined project approach. Follow the tide please, and there is no much value going against it.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro the SPA services in ASP.NET Core are obsolete if you didn't know https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12890

Comment: @LexLi it is not obsolete all they did was move it to a different Nuget Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions..... and it is basically the same thing.

Comment: Directly from microsoft "The features described in this article are obsolete as of ASP.NET Core 3.0. A simpler SPA frameworks integration mechanism is available in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions NuGet package. For more information, see [Announcement] Obsoleting Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices and Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0   so NO it is not obsolete.... it has just been simplified and moved to a new nuget

Comment: By the way I have done this many times... I currently lead a big project with react and .net 6.0

Comment: By the way i would disable typescript in visual studio and use VS Code for the REACT + Typescript part.... Visual Studio is pretty much useless for react and/or typescript-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are trying to achieve:

> Replace what you used to do in jQuery with React and to do so without
> having to move to the whole VSCode, Create-React-App (or Vite), "npm
> run stuff" environment.

You can indeed do so: I have setup a .Net6 project which is the standard MVC stuff that you are already used to, stripped out jQuery that comes with it, added Bootstrap 5 (no  jQuery) and then used this

<strike>(https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/add-react-to-a-website)</strike>

(https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gaearon/0275b1e1518599bbeafcde4722e79ed1/raw/db72dcbf3384ee1708c4a07d3be79860db04bff0/example.html) to actually add React just as a library - JSX included.

The final bit that is missing is the JSX babel warning I get. I just need to add something to my MSBuild that will minimise all my JavaScript and JSX components and I'm done.

Everything in Visual Studio too.

You can easily build components and I use a watcher on session storage to tell the state to render and it works pretty well.

The main reason I did it was so I didn't have to use NextJS because I don't see the point in learning/using NextJS and it's whole environment because its "Server Side Rendered" when that is what we have been doing for years in .Net MVC, Wordpress, and every framework/CMS you can think of.

Note, I am not against Next I am just at a point where I only use/learn tech if there is a benefit. I can clearly see the benefit of using React over jQuery.

My public facing app needs to be actual HTML coming from the server not a client side rendered page.

My private login area I build using Create-React-App (or maybe I'll switch to Vite - as I am rebuilding it) and I do all that in VSCode.